# Invalid parse session token after FB login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, parse-platform

I'm experiencing a problem with my parse app. I've Facebook linking functionality of the current anonymous user.

In the AppDelegate file I've this functionality:

```
if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
    PFAnonymousUtils.logInInBackground()
} else if (PFUser.currentUser() != nil && PFFacebookUtils.isLinkedWithUser(PFUser.currentUser()!)) {
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken())
}
```

But after the Facebook login/linking of the current user, in the next few app starts, error 209 is received.

I read almost all of the asked questions here, but nothing solves my problem.

When the user clicks on the Facebook login button:

```
if PFFacebookUtils.isLinkedWithUser(PFUser.currentUser()!) {
        PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(PFUser.currentUser()!, withReadPermissions: permissions, block: { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if success.boolValue {
                PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(PFUser.currentUser()!, withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken())
                self.obtainFacebookProfile()
            }
        })
    } else {
        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, block: { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }

            if user != nil {
                PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(user!, withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) 
                self.obtainFacebookProfile()
            }
        })
    }
```

I have the same implementation in my Android application and there is no such problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this problem by getting rid of Facebook login in the AppDelegate class. Since the current user is already linked with the Facebook profile, there is no need to do it again on app start because it generates a new session token. The problem is that maybe Parse isn't able to update the session token in the database before the next data request is made.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and it's clear that parse does not update the token in the User table after the token has expired. Could you explain more on how you fixed this? I can get a new FB token through the FBSDK but Parse still doesn't update the entry in the User table